# DB: how to handle large amount of CRUD queries properly due to a change that was made?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, performance, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

I am using `MongoDB` over a `Node.js` backend API. Works awesome.
When user inserts a new post, I want to update it's followers, it's followers are not officially listed as followers in a collection of `followers`, they are just potential users to be likely like his post.

For example, if one writes a post in some city that other marked as a key city, this post should be in his notification feed.

In order to do that, the Node.js backend API has to check each user if he has in his key cities the city that the poster posted.

If then, its should make another MongoDB query, which is inserting the notification, so it will be listen in the followers notifications feed.

And also, push a mobile app notification.

---

I know it has to be sliced into pieces, therefore I made the poster to only post his post, then to emit a socket to the server, telling that there some data need to be processed.

The server listens to the socket emit and starts finding and inserting the notification to the right places in DB.

After, the server runs another function sending push notifications via Google Firebase Cloud.

But I wonder, because now it works just perfect, if the same will be when the server should do that task for huge amount of rows, not just 5k users..

---

**Info about the ingredients of my project:**
Node.js, MongoDB, AngularJS and Express.

---

This is efficiency question, so I thought it will be wise to not bother you with ton of lines of code.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be better to ask this on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, or maybe on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if it can be narrowed down to a specific part with some code

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a scalable solution. An insert in one collection triggering a query to another collection that inserts subdocuments into an array is going to be a very heavy operation once you get a large number of users.

I would recommend having 3 collections to handle this task. One collection is for posts. One collection is for cities. And one collection is for users. Rather than inserting notifications to the user collection, insert the notifications into the cities collection. Each city will hold an array of notifications relevant to that city. Users can hold an array that holds their cities of interest that is used to pull in notifications from the cities collection. By setting it up this way, you are only updating one document with each post upload, instead of potentially a large number.

ex.

```
Post {title: 'my awesome post', url: 'awesomeurl.com'}
City {name: 'Los Angeles', state: 'CA', notifications: [{postTitle: 'my awesome post', url: 'awesomeurl.com'}, {postTitle: 'my lame post', url: 'lameurl.com'}]
User {firstName: 'raz', citiesOfInterest: ['Los Angeles', 'Denver']}
```

Note: This example could reduce data redundancy to be more efficient, but is left this way for readability.

Another benefit of not updating the user object is that it allows indexing of the cities of interest by each user. If a mobile push notification needs to go out to all users interested in 'Los Angeles,' an index will make this quick work (instead of an intensive operation that requires reading and possibly editing each object).